# The computer does not boot when RAM is placed in dual channel

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

Hi to make it more clear I will start with listing my setup:

**MOBO**: MSI Z170A Gaming Pro
**CPU**: i5 6600k
**RAM**:

1. Crucial Ballistix Sport DDR4 2400Mhz (4GB)
2. Crucial Ballistix Sport DDR4 2400Mhz (4GB)
3. Kingston Hyperx Fury DDR4 2133Mhz (8GB)

**What is the problem?**
The Ballistix RAM sticks does not work in Dual Channel Mode (computer does not boot up when I have only these RAM sticks inserted). I've inserted them into corrects slots (2nd and 4th DIMM slot counting from CPU).

**What have I already checked?**
I've just made a lot of memory tests using memtest86.

- testing each RAM separately in 2nd slot **(NO ERRORS)**
- testing Crucial Ballistix in 2nd slot and Kingston HyperX in 4th slot **(NO ERRORS)**
- testing Crucial Ballistix in 1st and 2nd slot and Kingston HyperX in 4th slot **(NO ERRORS)**
- testing Crucial Ballistix in 2nd and 3rd slot and Kingston HyperX in 4th slot **(infinite number of errors)**
- testing Crucial Ballistix in 1st and 2nd slot and Kingston HyperX in 3rd slot **(NO ERRORS)**
- testing Crucial Ballistix in 2nd and 4th slot **(PC DOES NOT BOOT UP, CANNOT ENTER THE MEMTEST)**

**Do you have any ideas what can be wrong?**
For me it seems that there is some problem with the Crucial Ballistix RAM working in the Dual-Channel mode. I'm wondering why does it happen.

[image]

**Update 12-10-22**

1. After turning on the computer with Crucial Ballistix RAM sticks inserted into the 2nd and 4th slots, the bios reset.

Comment: As for quick diagnose, try this options (only with Crucial sticks and no need for MemTest, just check if it starts): 
 | 
1. Update BIOS. | 
2. Reset bios settings with button/battery. | 
3. Disable dual channel, install two sticks, if they boot up, switch on xmp and dual channel. | 
4. Check sticks in second channel instead of first. | 
5. Get different pair (matching dual-boot set if possible) and check if it boots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it turned out that it was all okay with the Crucial Ballistix RAM sticks, I just needed to clean them gently with eraser and also clean the RAM slots. The funny fact is that I also had a slightly bent pin in the socket that was responsible for a memory controller. This whole situation was pure hardware learning for me and I hope I won't have any further problems.

Answer (score -1):

Just trying to write up with the best of my knowledge what is going on and some gentle pointers.

Firstly, you shouldn't mix match different speed memory module as you downgrade other faster modules to match that lower speed, it is just best practice to have the same size and same speed modules where possible - mixing memory can cause system instability even though working.

Looks like you have made good head way, but have you tried putting one crucial module in Slot 2 and one Crucial module in Slot 4 as per the manual?

[Motherboard Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1216922/Msi-Z170-A-Pro.html?page=21#manual)

I would suggest leaving the Kingston memory out of the equation for now and just testing the crucial memory modules in Slot 2 and 4 (Matching memory sticks) and see what happens as to Dual Memory mode.

I hope this helps!
Matthew

Comment: Hi!
As i mentioned in: What is the problem?
I tried to put Crucial in 2nd and 4th slot but the computer does not boot up.
I cannot enter the memtest86 with this setup.

Comment: Also try removing the bios battery for a few mins and then trying this config again. Are the Crucial memory modules matching (same serial number and revision)?

Comment: They were not bought in one package, they were bought separately. However I will check that in the evening today :)

Comment: Sorry for miss reading your post! Yeah, if they are even called the same but a different number of chips on the module or a different revision it will cause issues. They look like they both work as per your post, but I would suspect they are not a matching module set. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: It's fine to mix sizes and frequencies, as long as (1) the pairs that work in dual channel have the same size and frequencies (but not necessarily the same brand), and (2) the module with the lowest frequency meets the requirement of the motherboard.